# import local package during poetry run

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I just transitioned from `pipenv` to `poetry` and I'm having trouble importing a package from a local package I'm developing in a few of my scripts. To make this more concrete, my project looks something like:

```
pyproject.toml
poetry.lock
bin/
  myscript.py
mypackage/
  __init__.py
  lots_of_stuff.py
```

Within `myscript.py`, I `import mypackage`. But when I `poetry run bin/myscript.py` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` because the `PYTHONPATH` does not include the root of this project. With `pipenv`, I could solve that by specifying `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project/root` in a `.env` file, which would be automatically loaded at runtime. **What is the right way to import local packages with poetry?**

I ran across this piece on [using environment variables](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#using-environment-variables) but `export POETRY_PYTHONPATH=/path/to/roject/root` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Maybe you should install `mypackage` using poetry. From what I understand this adds the path to the root of your project to the PYTHONPATH. Have you tried running `poetry install` and making sure that `mypackage` gets installed inside the virtual environment of your project and running the script again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After quite a bit more googling, I stumbled on [the packages attribute within the tool.poetry section](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) for pyproject.toml files. To include local packages in distribution, you can specify

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry]
# ...
packages = [
    { include = "mypackage" },
]
```

Now these packages are installed in editable mode :)

Comment: This is only necessary if the name of the folder with the package data differs from what is written `[tool.poetry]` section for the keyword `name`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @finswimmer for the context. And thanks especially for making poetry, which is 10x better than pipenv IMHO

Comment: Thanks! This works after I included my folder with all code `{ include = "src" }`.  I wonder if I am missing some env var  as `poetry run h1-script` only works when I am in the `src` folder and not the project root folder..

Answer (score 24):

Adding a local package (in development) to another project can be done as:

```
poetry add ./my-package/
poetry add ../my-package/dist/my-package-0.1.0.tar.gz
poetry add ../my-package/dist/my_package-0.1.0.whl
```

If you want the dependency to be installed in editable mode you can specify it in the pyproject.toml file. It means that changes in the local directory will be reflected directly in environment.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
my-package = {path = "../my/path", develop = true}
```

With current preview release (1.2.0a) a [command line](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/3940) option was introduced, to avoid above manually steps:

```
poetry add --editable /path/to/package
```

Another ways of adding packages can be found on [poetry add](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) page

If the above doesn't work, you can take a look over additional steps detailed in this [discussion](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/1135#discussioncomment-1006192)

Comment: Today, poetry available version is 1.1.11, 1.2.0 still in alpha

Comment: however this pollutes pyproject.toml, which is under source control. This can cause troubles

Comment: @HAL9000 I agree, and have opened an [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8107) related to that.