# Correct way to use local depencies with Poetry

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

With the help of `poetry` I have written a packages and installed it in a `site-packages` directory.  I am now developing a second package, again with `poetry`, which imports the first.  However, by default, the venv created has the setting

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4691) about this feature.  I can obviously change the setting, but is there a better way, which preserves a greater degree of separation between the venv and the rest of the OS?

**Edit**

Actually it turns out that I can't change the configuration as indicated about, because I am installing to a non-standard site-packages directory.  So the question is more: How do I make `poetry` honour `$PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66474844/1409644).  I just added the dependency with

```
poetry add ../otherproj/othermod/dist/otherproj.othermod-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```